# Angular 5 - Http post method error

Tags: angular, angular5

I have migrated my project from angular 4 to 5. As part of the migration i have changed HttpModule to HttpClientModule.
Now i am getting the following error

```
: Argument of type '(res: Response) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: ArrayBuffer, index: number) => any'
```

The code is as follows

```
 apiResponse(auth, apiType) {
      return this.http.post(auth.url, auth.data, auth.options)
                    .map((res: Response) => res.json()).subscribe(
        response => {
          console.log(response)
        }
      );
  }
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: What are the `auth.options`? Are you sure you still need to be using `.json()` with `HttpClient` (see [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/http))? Please give a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

With the HttpClientModule you dont have to manually extract the JSON. So a service which was looking like that:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { UserModel } from './user.model';

    @Injectable()
    export class UserService {

      constructor(private http: Http) {}

      list(): Observable<UserModel> {
        return this.http.get('/api/users')
          .map(response => response.json())
      }
    }
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { UserModel } from './user.model';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  list(): Observable<UserModel> {
    return this.http.get('/api/users');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
apiResponse(auth, apiType) {
      return this.http.post(auth.url, auth.data, auth.options).subscribe(response => {
          console.log(response)
        }
      );
  }
```